# Simple Blackjack game: deck list becomes NoneType

Tags: python, list, types, nonetype, blackjack

I tired to make a simple blackjack game in Python. When executing the code, list of cards in deck (self.deck) creates problems - becomes NoneType, when it should be a list.

```
'''
This is a blackjack game for the project 2
'''
import random

cardsuits = ['Hearts', 'Diamonds', 'Spades', 'Clubs']
cardrank = ['Two','Three','Four','Five','Six','Seven','Eight','Nine','Ten','Jack','Queen','King','Ace']
cardvalues = {'Two':2, 'Three':3, 'Four':4, 'Five':5, 'Six':6, 'Seven':7, 'Eight':8, 'Nine':9, 'Ten':10, 'Jack':10, 'Queen':10, 'King':10, 'Ace':11}

class Card:
    #class card has two attributes: suit and rank. asking for string will result in rank of suit response. There is a value calcluated, using cardvalues dictionary.
    def __init__(self,suit,rank):
        self.suit = suit
        self.rank = rank
    def __str__(self):
        return self.rank + ' of ' + self.suit
    #def value(self):
    #   self.value = cardvalues[self.rank]
    #   #think about ace here; it can be worth 10 or 1 depending on hand 

class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.deck = []
        for suit in cardsuits:
            for rank in cardrank:
                self.deck.append(Card(suit,rank))
    def __str__(self):
        deck_comp = ""
        for card in self.deck:
            deck_comp = deck_comp + "\n" + card.__str__()
        return "Deck contains " + deck_comp

    def reroll(self):
        self.deck = random.shuffle(self.deck)
    def take_a_card(self):
        single_card = self.deck.pop()
        return single_card


class Hand:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []
        self.value = 0
        self.aces = 0
    def add_card(self, card):
        self.cards.append(card)
        self.value = self.value + cardvalues[card.rank]
        if card.rank == "Ace":
            self.aces = self.aces + 1
    def ace_adjust(self):
        if self.value > 21 and self.aces > 0:
            self.value = self.value - 10
            self.aces = self.aces -1

class Funds:
    def __init__(self):
        self.balance= 0
        self.bet = 0
    def winbet(self):
        self.balance = self.balance + self.bet * 2
    def losebet(self):
        self.bet = 0
    def draw(self):
        self.balance = self.balance + self.bet
        self.bet = 0


def Place_a_Bet():
    while True:
        placebetamount = int(input(print('Select amount you want to bet.')))
        if isinstance(placebetamount, int) == False:
            print('Invalid bet type. You have to input a digit.')
            continue
        elif placebetamount > PlayerFunds.balance:
            print('You tried to bet more money than you have available. You cannot bet more than: ' + PlayerFunds.balance)
            continue
        elif placebetamount <= 0:
            print('Invaild Bet. You have to bet a positive number.')
            continue
        else:
            PlayerFunds.balance = PlayerFunds.balance - placebetamount
            PlayerFunds.bet = placebetamount
            break

def hit(deck,hand):

    hand.add_card(CurrentGameDeck.take_a_card())
    hand.ace_adjust()

def hit_or_stand(deck, hand):
    global playing  # to control an upcoming while loop

    Decision = input(str(print('Your Turn. Type "Hit" to get another card. Type "Stand" to move onto Dealers move')))
    while True:
        if Decision == "Hit":
            hit(deck,hand)
        elif Decision == "Stand":
            playing = False
        else: 
            print('just Hit or Stand. Other inputs are invalid')
            continue
        break


def CardStateGame(PlayerHand, DealerHand):
    print('Dealer Shows : ' + DealerHand.cards[0] + ' out of ' + len(DealerHand.cards)) 
    print('Dealer score is :' + DealerHand.value)
    print('Your cards are ')
    for card in PlayerHand.cards:
        print(card)
    print('and their value is: ' + PlayerHand.value)

def CardStateEndgame(PlayerHand, DealerHand):
    print('Dealer value is ' + DealerHand.value + ' and his cards are: ')
    for card in DealerHand.cards:
        print(card)
    print('Your cards are ')
    for card in PlayerHand.cards:
        print(card)
    print('and their value is: ' + PlayerHand.value)

#end conditions
def player_bust(PlayerHand, PlayerFunds):
    print('Value of your cards (' + PlayerHand.value +') exceeds 21. You lose.')
    PlayerFunds.losebet()
def player_wins(PlayerFunds):
    print('You won.')
    PlayerFunds.winbet()
def dealer_bust(DealerHand, PlayerFunds):
    print('Dealer loses, because value of his cards (' + DealerHand.value +') exceeds 21')
    PlayerFunds.winbet()
def dealer_wins(PlayerFunds):
    print('Dealer won.')
    PlayerFunds.losebet()
def draw(PlayerFunds):
    print('Both participants have same values. Its a draw')
    PlayerFunds.draw()

#gameplay
print('This is a game of blackjack. You and the dealer (AI) will try to reach card value of 21, or just higher than your opponent. Scores higher than 21 will lose')
PlayerFunds = Funds()

while True:
    startamount = int(input(print('Select the amount of money you enter the game with. Try to keep it plausible')))
    if startamount <= 0 or isinstance(startamount, int) == False:
        print('You cant play with that amount of money. try again')
        continue
    else:
        PlayerFunds.balance = startamount
        break
playing = True
while True:

    CurrentGameDeck = Deck()
    CurrentGameDeck.reroll()

    Place_a_Bet()


    DealerHand = Hand()
    PlayerHand = Hand()

    DealerHand.add_card(CurrentGameDeck.take_a_card())  
    PlayerHand.add_card(CurrentGameDeck.take_a_card())
    DealerHand.add_card(CurrentGameDeck.take_a_card())
    PlayerHand.add_card(CurrentGameDeck.take_a_card())

    CardStateGame(PlayerHand, DealerHand)

    while playing == True:

        hit_or_stand(CurrentGameDeck,PlayerHand)

        CardStateGame(PlayerHand, DealerHand)

        if PlayerHand.value >21:
            player_bust(PlayerHand, PlayerFunds)
            break
    if PlayerHand.value <= 21:

        while DealerHand.value <17:
            hit(CurrentGameDeck, DealerHand)

        CardStateEndgame

    if DealerHand.value > 21:
        dealer_bust()
    elif DealerHand.value > PlayerHand.value:
        dealer_wins()
    elif PlayerHand.value > DealerHand.value:
        player_wins()
    elif PlayerHand.value == DealerHand.value:
        draw()

    newgame = 0
    newgame = input(print('Do you want to play again? Type Y or N'))

    if newgame.lower() == 'Y' and PlayerFunds.balance >=0:
        playing = True
        continue
    elif newgame.lower() == 'Y' and PlayerFunds.balance < 0:
        print('no more funds. GG')
        break
    else:
        print('thanks for playing')
        break
```

I tried to use only

```
cardsuits = ['Hearts', 'Diamonds', 'Spades', 'Clubs']
cardrank = ['Two','Three','Four','Five','Six','Seven','Eight','Nine','Ten','Jack','Queen','King','Ace']
cardvalues = {'Two':2, 'Three':3, 'Four':4, 'Five':5, 'Six':6, 'Seven':7, 'Eight':8, 'Nine':9, 'Ten':10, 'Jack':10, 'Queen':10, 'King':10, 'Ace':11}

class Card:
    #class card has two attributes: suit and rank. asking for string will result in rank of suit response. There is a value calcluated, using cardvalues dictionary.
    def __init__(self,suit,rank):
        self.suit = suit
        self.rank = rank
    def __str__(self):
        return self.rank + ' of ' + self.suit
    #def value(self):
    #   self.value = cardvalues[self.rank]
    #   #think about ace here; it can be worth 10 or 1 depending on hand 

class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.deck = []
        for suit in cardsuits:
            for rank in cardrank:
                self.deck.append(Card(suit,rank))
    def __str__(self):
        deck_comp = ""
        for card in self.deck:
            deck_comp = deck_comp + "\n" + card.__str__()
        return "Deck contains " + deck_comp

    def reroll(self):
        self.deck = random.shuffle(self.deck)
    def take_a_card(self):
        single_card = self.deck.pop()
        return single_card
```

and then

```
test = Deck()
```

allows me to shuffle the deck, and pop a single card out of it - so other parts of the code may be a problem, but I have no idea which, where and why.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please try to post a minimal Code example, not your whole program. You could also try to debug your program by yourself. Either using a debugger like [pdb](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/pdb.html) or print the state of your program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the future you should try to slim your code down to pinpoint the problem. Since the issue was surrounding the deck you only really needed to post that class. The error you are getting is because of this function below:

```
def reroll(self):
    self.deck = random.shuffle(self.deck)
```

If you take a look at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/random.html#random.shuffle) you will see that this function *shuffles in place*. Change the function to be this instead:

```
def reroll(self):
    random.shuffle(self.deck)
```